# Julia: How to compute mean by group using aggregate for IndexedTables.jl?

Tags: julia

I am trying to use the `aggregate` function to compute the mean of a variable by group

```
using Distributions, PooledArrays

N=Int64(2e9/8); K=100;

pool = [@sprintf "id%03d" k for k in 1:K]
pool1 = [@sprintf "id%010d" k for k in 1:(N/K)]

function randstrarray(pool, N)
    PooledArray(PooledArrays.RefArray(rand(UInt8(1):UInt8(K), N)), pool)
end

using JuliaDB
DT = IndexedTable(Columns([1:N;]), Columns(
  id1 = randstrarray(pool, N),
  v3 =  rand(round.(rand(Uniform(0,100),100),4), N) # numeric e.g. 23.5749
 ));

res = IndexedTables.aggregate(mean, DT, by=(:id1,), with=:v3)
```

How I get the error

```
MethodError: no method matching mean(::Float64, ::Float64)
Closest candidates are:
  mean(!Matched::Union{Function, Type}, ::Any) at statistics.jl:19
  mean(!Matched::AbstractArray{T,N} where N, ::Any) where T at statistics.jl:57
  mean(::Any) at statistics.jl:34
in  at base\<missing>
in #aggregate#144 at IndexedTables\src\query.jl:119
in aggregate_to at IndexedTables\src\query.jl:148
```

however

```
IndexedTables.aggregate(+ , DT, by=(:id1,), with=:v3)
```

works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

```
res = IndexedTables.aggregate_vec(mean, DT, by=(:id1,), with=:v3)
```

from help:

```
help?> IndexedTables.aggregate_vec
```

aggregate_vec(f::Function, x::IndexedTable)
Combine adjacent rows with equal indices using a function from vector to scalar, **e.g. mean**.

---

**Old answer:**

(I keep it because it was pleasant exercise (for me) how to create helper type and functions if something doesn't work like we want. Maybe it could help someone in future :)

---

I am not sure how do you like to aggregate mean. My idea is to calculate "center of gravity" for points with equivalent mass.

center of two points: G = (A+B)/2

adding (aggregating) third point C is (2G+C)/3  (2G because G's mass is A's mass +B's mass)

etc.

```
struct Atractor
     center::Float64
     mass::Int64
end

" two points create new atractor with double mass "
mediocre(a::Float64, b::Float64) = Atractor((a+b)/2, 2)

# pls forgive me function's name! :) 

" aggregate new point to atractor "
function mediocre(a::Atractor, b::Float64)
    mass = a.mass + 1  
    Atractor((a.center*a.mass+b)/mass, mass)
end
```

Test:

```
tst_array = rand(Float64, 100);

isapprox(mean(tst_array), reduce(mediocre, tst_array).center)
true  # at least in my tests! :) 

mean(tst_array) == reduce(mediocre, tst_array).center  # sometimes true
```

For aggregate function we need a little more work:

```
import Base.convert

" we need method for convert Atractor to Float64 because aggregate
  function wants to store result in Float64 "
convert(Float64, x::Atractor) = x.center
```

And now it (probably :P) works

```
res = IndexedTables.aggregate(mediocre, DT, by=(:id1,), with=:v3)
id1     │ 
────────┼────────
"id001" │ 45.9404
"id002" │ 47.0032
"id003" │ 46.0846
"id004" │ 47.2567
...
```

I hope you see that aggregating mean has impact to precision! (there is more sum and divide operations)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it how to reduce two numbers to one. `mean` is for arrays. So just use an anonymous function:

```
res = IndexedTables.aggregate((x,y)->(x+y)/2, DT, by=(:id1,), with=:v3)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not what the OP wants - I think he wants the mean of v3 values for all groups as given by v3 - i.e. `tapply(DT$v3, DT$id1, mean)` in R; or `[mean(subdf[:v3]) for subdf in groupby(DT, :id1)]` in DataFrames.

Comment: I'd love to have tapply in Julia (I know it's in RLEVectors.jl but that feels a little clunky)

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard Yes I am thinking about taking the mean of a the value by group.

Answer (score 0):

I'd really like to help you, but it took me 10 minutes to install all the packages and another few minutes to run the code and figuring out what it actually does (or doesn't). It would be great if you'd provide a "minimal working example", which focusses on the problem. In fact, the only requirement to reproduce your problem is seemingly `IndexedTables` and two random arrays.

(Sorry, this is not a complete answer, but too long to be a comment.)

Anyways, if you read the docstring of `IndexedTables.aggregate`, you see that it requires a function which takes two arguments and obviously returns a single value::

```
help?> IndexedTables.aggregate
  aggregate(f::Function, arr::IndexedTable)

  Combine adjacent rows with equal indices using the given 2-argument
  reduction function, returning the result in a new array.
```

You see in the error message you posted, that there is

```
no method matching mean(::Float64, ::Float64)
```

Since I don't know what you expect to be calculated, I now assume that you want to calculate the `mean` value of the two numbers. In this case you can define another method for `mean()`:

```
Base.mean(x, y) = (x+y) / 2
```

This will fulfil the `aggregate` function signature requirements. But I am not sure if this is what you want.